# Cocos2d-iphone: Sprites filesystem position for 2x retina files

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm pretty new to cocos2d. As I understand the retina images are authomatically loaded. Is it possible to put the retina files in a different folder ? Let me explain:

```
folder1 -> contains "image1.png" 
folder2 -> contains "image1@2x.png"
```

I simply cannot detect if the retina image are correctly loaded.

Comment: You can kept images in different folders.If you want to check which image gets loaded then you can check its texture size. From that, you can distinguish whether image for retina display is loaded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Xcode puts all resource files in the root folder of the app bundle, even if they were in different folders or groups in the Xcode project.

While you can set this up in both Xcode and cocos2d, it's much more trouble than its worth.

You can easily test which image version is loaded by making the images have different content temporarily. For example draw a red X on the Retina resolution image, then relaunch the app. Use the various Retina and non-Retina simulators to verify.

PS: cocos2d recommends against using the @2x suffixes, it has its own suffixes (-hd, -ipad, -ipadhd, -widehd and others).

Comment: I'm gonna to create this structure because cocos2d javascript bindings will read the files from different folders and to have a good project organization.